# Can't get value from GET method

Tags: php, forms, variables, get

I have a website with a list of products and each product has the option where you can send some information to an email address via simple form.

The form opens in a new window. It consists of one input field (for email address) and a submit button. Example of URL: .../send_email.php?productid=12345

Here is the form:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
  <input type="text" name="youremail" value="youremail"><br /><br />
  <input type="submit" name="sendsubmit" value="Send">
</form>
```

This is what I have for sending the form:

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['sendsubmit'])){

    $productid = $_GET['productid'];

    $youremail = $_POST['youremail'];
    $subject = "Product name";

    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
    if(!preg_match($email_exp,$youremail)) {
      echo 'Your email address does not appear to be valid.<br />';
    }

    mail($youremail, $subject, $productid);
  }
?>
```

The problem is I can't get the value of "productid". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try to get the product id before if(isset()) condition..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, instead of asking this question, you had to inspect an HTML code of your form and see what is wrong with it.
And only then you may ask a question, "what server variable contain full current url".

It is very important to check the result of your code. You cannot be a PHP user without constant use of such a practice.

as for your particilar problem - **just leave the action blank**:

```
<form method="post" action="">
```

Comment: I'm not really a PHP user and this is the first time I even heard about $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']. I tried many things before posting a question here, but nothing was working. I will look more into this.

Thank you for your answer!

Comment: well, you don't need to, as empty action will be a solution without employing any PHP variable at all

Comment: So, if the PHP code is in the same file, I can leave action empty in any case?

Answer (score 2):

`$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` does not include the query string. You want `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`.

Answer (score 0):

if the whole process you are doing in send.php file, use `$_GET['productid']` before `if(isset($_POST['sendsubmit']))` like

```
$productid = (isset($_GET['productid'])) ? $_GET['productid'] : 'error';
```

Answer (score 0):

verify that the url called with submit ($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) contains ?productid=12345

Answer (score -1):

`$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` does not include the query string.

Try `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?'.$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` instead.

Comment: I wouldn't call this solution a bullet-proof one. Say, for the rewritten urls it won't help. Either use REQUEST URI or just leave the action blank, to make it solid and portable.

Comment: I think in my case it's best if I leave it blank.